# Internet Explorer Developer Tools how to preserve log upon navigation?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, error-logging

I'm looking for the way to log stuff in Internet Explorer Developer Console that preserve page refresh.

Under Google Chrome and Firefox's Firebug it's an option for that, but I could not find it under IE.

I'm using IE 9.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In IE Developer Cosole go to Tools -> Clear Entries on Navigate and uncheck what you want to stay in log.

Comment: it doesn't show in IE 11 ... Where is is this Tools -> Clear entries on navigate?

Answer (score 18):

In Internet Explorer 11 there is now a button ("Clear entries on navigate") which one must toggle for enabling/disabling the IE to clear the network logs on navigation or even http redirect.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx

[image]

Comment: It does not apply to the Console tab but to the Network tab... I guess there's no corresponding option available in the Console!

Comment: This isn't a button we can toggle but just a button to **clear the session** which is exactly the opposite of this question

Answer (score 14):

In **Internet Explorer 11** there is a button that you can click to delete or preserve console logs on navigation. If you want to **preserve** your console logs, then just **untick the button** (*highlighted red in my screenshot*).

[image]

Comment: For the benefit of other people, this screenshot appears to be from **IE11 on Windows 10**, as I don't see this option show up in IE11 on Windows 8.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Clear entries on navigate]

Clear entries on navigate is a toggle switch with on and off states. When in the off state, network traffic for a window or tab is recorded continuously as the browser moves from page to page. When in the on state, recorded traffic is cleared each time you navigate to a new page. This is turned on by default.

*Please note: Dev tools will close if the redirected domains navigate from a protected mode site to a non-protected mode site, e.g. from internet zone to intranet zone*