# IE11 Devtools - persist console logs across URLs

Tags: internet-explorer-11, devtools, ie-developer-tools, ie11-developer-tools

IE11 Devtools - I know there is a way to persist console logs on navigation. (See the answer at the bottom [of this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600486/internet-explorer-developer-tools-how-to-preserve-log-upon-navigation/28901652)).

However, this only appears to work if I am navigating between URLs of the same domain.

If I navigate from, say, www.abc.com (with Devtools open and console logs set to persist) to www.google.ca, then the Devtools bar closes itself and I lose all my console logs.

Is there a way to, on navigating between different domains, 1) keep the Devtools bar open, and 2) persist console logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are the IE tools closing between the cross domain navigation? In IE if you navigate from a domain that is in one zone (say Trusted Sites) to another domain in a different zone (e.g. Internet) then IE will restart the tab under the covers, as a new process needs to be created to match the integrity level for that Zone. If that's the case then the IE dev tools will close and there is simply no way to persist the logs. What you can do to workaround the issue is make sure the two domains you are navigating between are in the same zone.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test on my site and I find that I am able to keep the log on the navigation to other site.

Testing result with IE 11:

[image]

It can be possible that any IE settings cause this behavior on your side. For testing purpose you can try to make a test on any other machine to check the result.

Try to check IE settings on your side. If issue persist than try to reset IE may help to solve the issue.